# What encoding is this?

Tags: php, encoding

How can I determine what encoding this string is?

```
Sometimes, itÃ¢Â€Â™s the little things that make us the happiest.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's UTF-8 decoded as Latin-1 encoded as UTF-8 decoded as CP1252.

```
>>> u'Ã¢Â€Â™'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'\u2019'
```

Seriously... who does this?

Comment: I got as far as figuring that it was a *triple*-encode bug and sighed :)

Comment: How on earth did you figure that out?

Comment: Also, it's got a typographical right quotation mark in place of what obviously *should* be an apostrophe.

Comment: @Lèse -- UTF-8 double-encoding has a trademark: lots of appearances of characters in the range U+00C0 to U+00C3 (various accented uppercase A's) because the UTF-8-encodes of the chars from 128-255 start with 0xc0 through 0xc3 :)

Comment: @hobbs: Ah, now I know what to watch out for. I'm always seeing poorly encoded webpages, but I can never get some of them to render properly in my browser by changing encodings. Maybe those were double/triple encoded.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I should fix this in PHP?  And for the record... it's the woot.com api

Comment: @Webnet: I had to use 2 `iconv()` calls, one from UTF-8 to CP1252, and another from UTF-8 to ISO8859-1.

Comment: Sorry, can you show me a code example?  I've never had an issue with encoding before

Comment: `$output = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $input);`

Comment: I deal with this often when decoding wrongly-encoded Hebrew Gibberish on http://gibberish.co.il however I never knew the reason for the abundance of accented A's. Thank you for the explanation! As to who does this, anybody who cuts and pastes text from/to Outlook or Internet Explorer to/from applications with poor UTF-8 support.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: It's been a while, but do you have any method of determining which two encodings to encode as? Or do you just use all the permutations of the common encodings?

Comment: @dotancohen: The "from" is determined by examining the current output. The "to" is almost always UTF-8, unless you have reason to suspect that it's something else.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Thanks. I figured that the 'to' would almost always be 'UTF-8' in the case of many accented A's, but I would love to know how to "examine the output" to determine the 'from'. I've googled around a bit but I can find no info on this. What signs would I look for to know which encodings to use in `encode()`? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @dotancohen: The accented As indicate a "from" of Latin-1. The rest is just experience.